# Stopping time sigma Algebra and its enlargement

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times, filtrations

In the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$
let $\mathcal{F} = \{ \mathcal{F}_t : t\in\mathbb{R} \}$ be a Filtration, 
$\mathcal{A}_0 \subset \mathcal{A}$ a sub-$\sigma$-field and $\tau$ a $\mathcal{F}$-stopping time. Define the enlarged filtration
$\mathcal{G} = \{ \mathcal{G}_t : t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ through
$\mathcal{G}_t = \sigma(\mathcal{F}_t \cup \mathcal{A}_0)$;
$\tau$ is also a $\mathcal{G}$-stopping time.
The stopped $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ is defined as the collection of all sets $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $A\cap\{\tau\leq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$; and $\mathcal{G}_\tau$ similar.

Is $\mathcal{G}_\tau = \sigma(\mathcal{F}_\tau \cup \mathcal{A}_0)$ true?
I'm especially interested in $\mathcal{G}_\tau \subset \sigma(\mathcal{F}_\tau \cup \mathcal{A}_0)$.

Thx for any help in advance!